# How do I enable the next button after selecting the radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I enable the next button after selecting the radio button?
in step by step form with js

```
<form name="voting">

    <input type="radio" class="btn" value="yes" name="aaa" />yes<br>
    <input type="radio" class="btn" value="no" name="aaa" />no<br>
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="next" />
</form>
```

Comment: With an on change handler on the radio buttons. If you show us you have done something already we will help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `disabled` property to button. Then add the event handler on change & set`disabled` property to false

```js
$(".aaa").change(function() {
  $(".next").prop('disabled',false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="voting">

    <input type="radio" class="btn aaa" value="yes" name="aaa" />yes<br>
    <input type="radio" class="btn aaa" value="no" name="aaa" />no<br>
    <input type="button" class="btn next" value="next" disabled="disabled"/>
</form>
```

Comment: no need for `.is(":checked")`. Can't uncheck a radio. Use of `prop()` also more common approach